# UITableView with custom class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have created a derived class from UITableView which will contain some custom logic. But I am not sure how to get it to populate cells.

h. file:

```
@interface MetricsView : UITableView {
    @private
    NSMutableArray *_items;
}
@end
```

m. file:

```
    @implementation MetricsView

    //this gets called
    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
    {
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        if (self) {
            _items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Name:", nil];
        }
        return self;
    }

//this never gets called??
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    //this never gets called??
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [_items count];
    }

//this never gets called??
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MetricsViewCell";

        MetricsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        [cell setupWithName:[_items objectAtIndex:0] withData:[_items objectAtIndex:0]];
        return cell;
    }

    @end
```

I created MetricsView on top of my ViewController. Here's what storyboard looks like:

[image: Here's what storyboard looks like:]

Do I need to add some custom initialization code inside ViewController.m?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let's put things straight. Your `UITableView` is the view. You can indeed subclass it but it does not seems to be what you want. What I feel you're trying to do is create your custom `UITableView` `delegate` and `dataSource`. Meaning a custom class that does obey to those two protocol. You don't need to subclass your UITableView but you need to set your custom class to be the delegate of your `UITableView`. And in this class you will be able to implement the method you're trying to implement (-cell for row at index path, -number of row in section, -number of section). What you need is to subclass the well where your tableview will get the water (water being info on what to put in the cell and how many cell to create). I hope this will help!

Comment: so now I receive "malloc: *** error for object 0x75610453: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug" after I call setDataSource. My MetricsView is no longer a custom class, just default UITableView. Do I need to call metricsView alloc myself?

Answer (score 1):

```
//this never gets called??
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

That and the other methods are *data source* methods. They will not be called unless you set this class as the table view's data source.

Oddly, you have put this code inside the UITableView subclass itself. Okay, that's weird and it violates MVC, but you can do it if you really want to. But then you must set the UITableView subclass as its own data source (and, presumably, its own delegate). That isn't going to happen all by itself; you must do it.

LATER EDIT: However, in general I would cast doubt on the need and desirability of subclassing UITableView in the first place. It's hard for me to think of a situation where this would be useful to do. Just put your table view in the interface, hook its `delegate` and `datasource` outlets to the View Controller, and you're done. Now the view controller gets the `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and other calls, as rightly it should.

Comment: I think he just didn't figured yet the difference between the UITableView subclass itself and the delegate/data source.

Comment: @Nicolas I vaguely understand it. Just started learning Objective C.

Comment: do I add <UITableViewDelegatte, UITableViewDataSource> to my MetricsView interface and then link it via storyboard somehow?

Comment: you can add <UITableViewDelegatte, UITableViewDataSource> to any custom class you want. What you need is to set your tableview.delegate = customClass and your tableview.dataSource = customClass so that your tableview know where to look for data

Comment: @MikhailNaumov Here are the relevant sections of my book: [Delegate](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_delegation) — [Data source](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_data_sources) — [Table view data in general](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_table_view_data)